# Strict inequality for floating point multiplication

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

Suppose *a*, *x*, and *y* are positive IEEE floating point numbers with
*x* < *y*.  Prove that *a*×*x* < *a*×*y* where ×
denotes floating-point multiplication rounding to nearest.

Naively, you might suppose that for some *a* and for *x* close to *y*,
you would get *a*×*x* = *a*×*y*.  It turns out that this
can't happen (as long as denormalized numbers, infinities, and NaNs are
excluded).

I'm interested in an elegant proof and, if possible, a book or paper
where this is given.

**TAKE 2**: As the reply by Pascal Cuoq shows, the statement above is
false.  How about the restricted version with *y* = 1?  Here is the
statement to be proved:

Suppose *a* and *x* are positive IEEE floating point numbers with
*x* < 1.  Prove that *a*×*x* < *a* where ×
denotes floating-point multiplication rounding to nearest.

Comment: Since infinity can be positive in IEEE I'm not sure such a proof is possible. Did you mean to exclude infinity?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out.  I edited the question to exclude infinities and NaNs as well as denormalized numbers.

Comment: If you want to change your question, the general advice would be to ask a new one. PS: I believe the new property you are interested in is true.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: yes, it is true under reasonable assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a formal proof to your revised question (with slightly altered language):

> Suppose `a` and `x` are positive IEEE floating point numbers with `x < 1`. Prove that `[ax] < a` where `[]` denotes default floating-point rounding.

WLOG, let `a` be in `[1, 2)`.  The statement is trivially true if `a` is `1`, so we actually only need to consider `a` in `(1,2)`.  `x < 1` implies that `x <= 1 - u/2`, where `u = ulp(1) = ulp(a)`.  We have:

```
ax <= a - au/2
```

We also have `a > 1`, so `au/2 > u/2`, so:

```
ax <= a - au/2 < a - u/2
```

Because `ax` is more than half an ulp below `a`, `[ax] < a`.

Comment: Thanks.  A corollary of this result is that successively multiplying a number by (1 - u/2) marches downwards through all floating point numbers (until the minimum normalized number is reached).  Furthermore (?) dividing by (1 - u/2) marches in the opposite direction.

Comment: @cffk “through all” no.

Comment: Addressing just the issue of multipling by x = (1 - u/2).  We know that
ax < a.  Indeed we have ax = nextafter(a, 0); so repeatedly executing
a *= x, we march down through successive floating point numbers.  (Assume
numbers are positive; exclude denormalized numbers, etc.)

Comment: @cffk: Yes. a - u < ax < a - u/2, hence [ax] = nextDown(a).  (The analysis at binade crossings is different, but trivial).

Answer (score 7):

The property is false, as shown by the following C99 program when compiled with a compiler providing IEEE binary64 for `double` and `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`=0:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void) {
  double z = 1.0;
  double y = nextafter(z, 0.0);
  double x = nextafter(y, 0.0);
  double a = 1.0 + 2 * DBL_EPSILON;

  printf("%a %a\n", a*x, a*y);
}
```

Result:

```
0x1.0000000000001p+0 0x1.0000000000001p+0
```

That's `y` the predecessor of 1.0, `x` the predecessor of `y`, and `a` the successor of the successor of 1.0. The values of `x` and `y` are at the top of their [binade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binade), where relative precision is best, and the values of `a*x` and `a*y` are at the bottom of theirs, where relative precision is worst. This is how `a*x` and `a*y` get rounded to the same value.

The property in the question looks true because a counter-example can only happen with `x` and `y` separated by a single ULP and the multiplication by `a` sending them relatively lower in the destination binade than they were in the origin binade.

Comment: Did you mean `x` the *predecessor* of `y`?

Comment: @njuffa Yes, I shouldn't answer SO questions before I have had coffee.

Comment: That's a problem I know all too well :-)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.